# Not able to use keyboard when stdin redirection, batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, stdin

I have this batch file:

```
 @echo off
 echo c:\temp\MyProgram.exe > commands.txt
 runas /profile /savecred /user:user1 "cmd /k remote /c computerB session_1 < commands.txt"
 ....
```

Explication:
I connect remotley to comupterB with the user1 and execute MyProgram.exe (That is in computerB). MyProgram.exe execute in console and  wait action from the user (Type arguments). The problem is I'm not able to type anything from keyboard in MyProgram console, it seems the keyboard is ignored completly !.
I know that I must switch to stdin=0 for keyboard but I don't know how to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you redirect stdin with `cmd /k ... < commands.txt`, you're losing stdin. Why would you expect to get it back? All child processes inherit their base (0, 1, and 2) file descriptors.

Is `commands.txt` a batch file? If so, why not run it instead of redirect commands from it?
You could copy that file to the remote machine, then invoke it, leaving cmd open.

```
runas /user:user1 "cmd /k remote /c computerB session_1 call c:\temp\commands.cmd"
```

When I do this, the cmd window is still left open and I can type into it.

Comment: Remote open a session on computerB, all commands I type will executed in computerB, is for that I used "< commands.txt" to pass commands to Remote. If I use Call c:\temp\..., the commands will be executed in local. Thanks

Comment: If you copy `commands.cmd` to `C:\temp` on the remote machine, then the example I've given will run `commands.cmd` on the remote machine because the command that's being run remotely is `call C:\temp\commands.cmd`.